# Golem: object 'input' not found, or function not recognised

Tags: shiny, golem

I have a module initiated with `golem::add_module(name = "my_module", with_test = TRUE)`.
I have also created a function file with `golem::add_fct("my_module", with_test = TRUE)`.

My module is a bit lengthy, but to resume: I have some radioButtons at the top and I want to store input$myRadioButtons in a reactive function.

Inside the server of *my_module*, I am writing `myRadio <- reactive({ return(input$myRadioButtons) })`.
When I call myRadio() below and running the app, I am getting "function myRadio() not found".

I tried swapping the function from a reactive to a normal function `myRadio <- function(){ return(input$myRadioButtons) })` but I still get the "function not found" prompt.

Now, I tried moving either the reactive version of myRadio or the normal function version of myRadio to the *fct_my_module* file, but this time I am prompted with "object 'input' not found".

Writing the function inside the module server does not recognise it, and writting it inside the helper fct_ file (which is outside the server) does not recognise the input.. I am at a loss.

Any help much appreciated, thank you very much in advance!

Edit: Here is what I am doing

```
#' my_module UI Function
#'
#' 
#'
#' @param id,input,output,session Internal parameters for {shiny}.
#'
#' @noRd
#'
#' @importFrom shiny NS tagList
mod_my_module_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(

    radioButtons(ns(myRadioButtons), label = 'Pick one', choices = c('a','b','c')),
    textOutput(ns(text)),
    textOutput(ns(text2))

  )

}

#' main Server Functions
#'
#' @noRd
mod_my_module_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    # This works
    output$text <- renderText(input$myRadioButtons)
    
    # This doesn't work:
    myRadio <- reactive({ return(input$myRadioButtons) })
    output$text2 <- renderText({ myRadio() })
    
    # This doesn't work either (commenting it out)
    # myRadio <- function(){ return(input$myRadioButtons) })
    # output$text2 <- renderText({ myRadio() })

  })
}

## To be copied in the UI
# mod_my_module_ui("main_1")

## To be copied in the server
# mod_my_module_server("main_1")
```

Above prompts me with "function 'myRadio()' not found", and when I move it to the external fct___ file the function is found, but the *input* is not found.

Comment: It's hard to know how to help you without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Try to convert your golem app to the simplest app that still has this problem

Comment: Did you call your code `myRadio <- reactive({ return(input$myRadioButtons) })` inside a reactive environment ? Like a `render*()` function ?

Comment: Yes I am calling it from inside a reactive environment. I have updated above with a minimum module example. The module is correctly called from the golem "app_ui.R" script.

Comment: I think I am having the same issue or something close to it.   I am calling a function in the utils_helpers.R file from a reactive function in the server part of a golem module.  Seems like the code calling the function form the utils_helpers.R file needs a namespace.  But I have no idea what that would be.